# Count n-tuples in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with two int columns, the combination of them is unique.

```
ids  idk
---------
1    2
1    3
1    4

2    2
2    3
2    4

3    2
3    5
3    4

4    2
4    3
```

What I want is to get the biggest set of idks which is common to at least 2 ids.

The result here should look like this:

```
(2,3,4) - 2x
(2,4) - 3x
(2,3) - 3x
(3,4) - 2x
(2,5) - 1x
```

As you see, the number of common idks is the most important thing. If the number is the same #(2,4) = #(2,5) then the criterion is the number of occurencies.

It seems to me rather like a algorithm which needs to be programmed but I may be wrong and SQL is capable of it.

Comment: Vitalii - do you mean max # of idk values?  For example, if he was looking for the count of the common set of 2 idks, this would be relatively easy.  If looking for common set of 2 or 3 idks, it's still feasible (but becomes memory intensive with larger data sets and straight SQL).

Comment: This is a trivial problem via a programming language, but a hard (and inefficient) one for straight SQL on most databases (assuming an unbounded idk).  If you can only use SQL only, consider leveraging the stored procedure logic within your DBMS to perform some/all of the logic

Comment: I would not do that. That is the sort of problem some mathematician specialized in theory of sets might answer this. I would try to "flatten" the combinations and then count them. But since these are integers the number of combinations are too big for any SQL. Are the idks in a certain range (e.g. 1-9) then I would just for the fun of it write a SELECT statement capable to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!  I think I've found a way to solve it in SQL Server.  Still it's rather complicated:

- Create a stored procedure that calculates combinations
- Call the stored procedure to create a list of combinations for each `ids`
- Increate the occurance by 1 for each combination that was previously found
- Insert new combinations into a result table

Here's the full code:

```
set nocount on

-- Helper table for sp_Combinations
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#combos') is not null
    drop table #combos
create table #combos (
    comboid int default 1,
    basecomboid int,
    combosize int default 1,
    val int,
    primary key (comboid, val))


if OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_Combinations') is null
    exec ('create procedure dbo.sp_Combinations as select 1')
go
-- Creates a list of all combinations of values in #combos,
-- based on a starting list with comboid = 1
alter procedure dbo.sp_Combinations
as begin
    delete from #combos where comboid <> 1

    declare @n int
    select @n = count(*) from #combos

    update #combos set combosize = (select count(*) from #combos)

    if @n = 1
        return

    -- Add individual numbers
    insert  #combos 
            (comboid, basecomboid, val) 
    select  row_number() over (order by val) + 1
    ,       1
    ,       val 
    from    #combos 
    where   comboid = 1

    declare @k int
    set @k = 1
    while @k + 1 < @n
        begin
        declare @max_combo_id int
        select @max_combo_id = max(comboid) from #combos

        -- Add one new member to each combination of size @k
        -- The new member must be larger than all existing members
        -- F.e. for @n = 4 and @k = 1:
        --       (1) --> (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)
        --       (2) --> (2,3) (2,4)
        --       (3) --> (3,4)
        --       (4) --> no new combinations
        ;with b as (
            select  val
            from    #combos
            where   comboid = 1
        ), g as (
            select  comboid
            ,       max(val) as maxval
            from    #combos c
            where   combosize = @k
            group by
                    comboid
        )
        insert  #combos (comboid, basecomboid, combosize, val)
        select  row_number() over (order by g.comboid) + @max_combo_id
        ,       g.comboid
        ,       @k + 1
        ,       b.val
        from    b
        join    g
        on      b.val > g.maxval

        -- Add the members of the base combo
        insert  #combos (comboid, basecomboid, combosize, val)
        select  l.comboid
        ,       l.basecomboid
        ,       l.combosize
        ,       b.val
        from    #combos l
        join    #combos b
        on      b.comboid = l.basecomboid
        where   l.combosize = @k + 1

        set @k = @k + 1
        end
end
go
go

-- Input table
declare @t table (ids int, idk int)
insert into @t (ids, idk) values 
    (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), 
    (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), 
    (3, 2), (3, 5), (3, 4), 
    (4, 2), (4, 3);

-- Valid combinations with number of occurrences
declare @combinations table (comboid int, val int, cnt int)

-- Iterate over all ids    
declare cur cursor for select distinct ids from @t
open cur
declare @ids int
while 1=1
    begin
    fetch from cur into @ids
    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        break

    -- Calculate combinations for this ids
    truncate table #combos
    insert into #combos (comboid, val) select 1, idk from @t where ids = @ids
    exec dbo.sp_Combinations

    -- Increase count of existing combinations
    update  u
    set     cnt = cnt + 1
    from    @combinations u
    where   exists
            (
            select  *
            from    @combinations a
            full join
                    #combos b
            on      a.val = b.val
            where   a.comboid = u.comboid
            group by
                    a.comboid
            having  max(case when a.val is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                    and max(case when b.val is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
            )

    -- Insert new combinations
    declare @max_combo_id int
    select @max_combo_id = isnull(max(comboid),0) from @combinations

    insert  @combinations
            (comboid, val, cnt)
    select  n.comboid + @max_combo_id
    ,       n.val
    ,       1
    from    #combos n
    where   not exists
            (
            select  *
            from    @combinations a
            full join
                    #combos b
            on      a.val = b.val
            where   b.comboid = n.comboid
            group by
                    b.comboid
            having  max(case when a.val is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                    and max(case when b.val is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
            )
    end

close cur
deallocate cur

-- Display result
select  x.r as combination
,       cnt as occurrences
from    (
        select  distinct comboid
        ,       cnt
        from    @combinations
        ) a
cross apply
        (
        select  val as [text()]
        from    @combinations c
        where   c.comboid = a.comboid
        for xml path('')
        ) x(r)
where   a.cnt > 1
order by
        len(x.r) desc
,       cnt desc
```

For your example data set, this prints:

```
combination occurrences
234         2
23          3
24          3
34          2
2           4
3           3
4           3
```